# Loop space of hom space $\Omega[X,Y]$ is the same as $[X, \Omega Y]$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $Y$ is a based space with basepoint $b$. The (unpointed) hom space $[X,Y]$ has a natural choice of basepoint, i.e. $c_b$, the constant map sending everything to $b$ - so we can consider the loop space $\Omega[X,Y]$. Is it true that there's a homeomorphism
$$\Omega[X,Y] \cong [X, \Omega Y]$$

The comments in the answer of the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783877/classification-of-homotopy-classes-of-lifts) seem to suggest so, but I don't see why.